# How to get messages as a thread in sequence from onee table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, multithreading, chat

Here is my structure of "dms" table

```
id uuid
sender_id uuid
receiver_id uuid
message varchar
created_at timestamp
```

I want to get messages as threads of each individual pair in the form of group. For example let say we have 3 users user1, user2, user3, now I want to get first thread between user1 and user2 and then maybe of user3 and user1 if they any message among them.

I have tried the following query for one particular user but it is just grouping on each side messages but not combining messages of both parties as a thread

```
SELECT
    sender_id,
    receiver_id,
    array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
        'message', (metadata->'message')::text,
        'created_at', created_at
    ) ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS thread
FROM
    dms
WHERE
    sender_id = 'AAA' OR receiver_id = 'AAA'
GROUP BY
    sender_id,
    receiver_id,
    created_at
ORDER BY
    created_at ASC;
```

The expected output for user 'AAA' I want is like this

```
sender_id.         receiver_id     message

AAA                BBB             message from AAA
BBB                AAA             message from BBB
CCC                AAA             message from CCC
AAA                CCC             message from AAA
AAA                DDD             message from AAA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are inconsistencies between the original post's table description, query, and expected output; however, the following query should be sufficient to demonstrate an approach to achieve the desired results:

```
WITH dms(id, sender_id, receiver_id, message, created_at) AS (
  VALUES (1, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'message', clock_timestamp()::timestamp),
         (2, 'CCC', 'AAA', 'message', clock_timestamp()::timestamp),
         (3, 'BBB', 'AAA', 'message', clock_timestamp()::timestamp),
         (4, 'AAA', 'CCC', 'message', clock_timestamp()::timestamp),
         (5, 'AAA', 'DDD', 'message', clock_timestamp()::timestamp)),
threads AS (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEAST(dms.sender_id, dms.receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)) AS thread_id,
         LEAST(dms.sender_id, dms.receiver_id) AS participant1,
         GREATEST(dms.sender_id, dms.receiver_id) AS participant2,
         dms.*
    FROM dms)
SELECT  threads.thread_id,
        MIN(threads.participant1) AS participant1,
        MIN(threads.participant2) AS participant2,
        ARRAY_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('sender_id', threads.sender_id,
                                    'receiver_id', threads.receiver_id,
                                    'message', threads.message,
                                    'created_at', threads.created_at) ORDER BY created_at) AS thread
  FROM threads
  GROUP BY threads.thread_id
  ORDER BY threads.thread_id;
```

The key to this type of query is identifying the grouping criteria. In this case, grouping is by thread which is determined by the combination of `sender_id` and `receiver_id`. The `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions are used to ensure consistent ordering of the participants' IDs regardless of their role in the message.

To efficiently filter by participants, put the selection critieria in the `threads` subquery.